# Parameter not being used in function C++

Tags: c++, function, syntax

I am making a program that will read from a file and output the data both on screen and in a file.  I had it working prior to adding an Overall Average and Total Count, but now it just crashes with no errors in the compliling process.

I have searched similar threads, but am unable to find anything that helps me fix these errors.  Any assistance is appreciated.

Edit: updated teh code with some of the changes suggested.  Now just crashing w/ no errors.

```
                          #include <iostream>
            #include <string>
            #include <limits>
            #include <cmath>
            #include <iomanip>
            #include <fstream>

            using namespace std;

            void gradeCalc(int studentID, int count, double midterm, double finalExam, double researchPaper, double groupProject, double participation, double studentAvg, double& overallAvg, double gradeSum);
            void printGrade(int studentID, int count, double midterm, double finalExam, double researchPaper, double groupProject, double participation, double studentAvg, double& overallAvg, double gradeSum);

            int main()
            {
                int studentID;
                int count = 0;

                double midterm;
                double finalExam;
                double researchPaper;
                double groupProject;
                double participation;
                double studentAvg;
                double overallAvg;
                double gradeSum;

                gradeCalc(studentID, count, midterm, finalExam, researchPaper, groupProject, participation, studentAvg, overallAvg, gradeSum);
                printGrade(studentID, count, midterm, finalExam, researchPaper, groupProject, participation, studentAvg, overallAvg, gradeSum);

                return 0;
            }

            void printGrade(int studentID, int count, double midterm, double finalExam, double researchPaper, double groupProject, double participation, double studentAvg, double& overallAvg, double gradeSum)
            {

                ifstream infile;
                ofstream outfile;

                infile.open("grades.dat");
                outfile.open("grades.txt");
                outfile << "STUDENT GRADING REPORT: ";
                outfile << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);

                while (!infile.eof()) {

                    infile >> studentID >> midterm >> finalExam >> researchPaper >> groupProject >> participation;

                    if (studentID > 1 && studentID <= 999) {

                        outfile << endl
                                << "Student ID: " << studentID << ' ' << "Midterm: " << midterm << ' ' << "Final Exam: " << finalExam << ' ' << "Research Paper: " << researchPaper << ' ' << "Group Project: " << groupProject
                                << "Participation: " << participation << ' ' << "Student Average: " << studentAvg;
                    }
                    overallAvg = gradeSum / count;
                    outfile << endl
                            << "Total # of Students: " << count
                            << "Overall Class Average: " << overallAvg;
                }

                infile.close();
                outfile.close();
            };

            void gradeCalc(int studentID, int count, double midterm, double finalExam, double researchPaper, double groupProject, double participation, double studentAvg, double& overallAvg, double gradeSum)
            {

                //midterm = .25
                //finalExam = .25
                //researchPaper = .20
                //groupProject = .20
                //participation = .10

                ifstream infile;
                ofstream outfile;

                infile.open("grades.dat");

                while (!infile.eof()) {

                    infile >> studentID >> midterm >> finalExam >> researchPaper >> groupProject >> participation;
                    studentAvg = ((midterm * .25) + (finalExam * .25) + (researchPaper * .20) + (groupProject * .20) + (participation * .10));
                    overallAvg = gradeSum / count;

                    if (studentID > 1 && studentID <= 999) {
                        count++;
                        gradeSum += studentAvg;

                        cout << endl
                             << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << "Student ID: " << studentID << ' ' << "Average:  " << studentAvg;
                    }
                    cout << endl
                         << "Total # of Students: " << count
                         << "Overall Class Average: " << overallAvg;
                }

                infile.close();
            };
```

Comment: What command are you using to compile? Certain compiler flags will throw an error if you don't use arguments passed to a function.

Comment: The error messages aren't as helpful as they could be, but the indentation of the code lines you added is a clue:  you have semicolons that you need to remove.

Comment: Note your question title describes the warnings, not the errors. So which lines are 56 and 91?

Comment: Unrelated: `cout << endl
                         << "Total # of Students: " << count;
                    << "Overall Class Average: " << overallAvg;` Got an extra semi colon in there.

Comment: Unrelated: Recommended reading: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: You try to modify values which are not passed by reference so the modification will not be accessible in main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some syntax issues you need to resolve:

`printGrade()`:

```
    outfile << endl
            << "Total # of Students: " << count; //<-- bad semicolon
    << "Overall Class Average: " << overallAvg;
```

`gradeCalc()`:

```
    cout << endl
            << "Total # of Students: " << count; //<-- bad semicolon
    << "Overall Class Average: " << overallAvg;
```

Comment: i have made those changes, but now it just crashes. here is the updated code: https://pastebin.com/60haZ7eV

Comment: @CharlesCarrington sounds like you have a new question. Take a few kicks at solving it, Gustavo 's comment under the question may help, and ask a new question if you get stuck.

Answer (score 1):

`printGrade` takes `overallAvg` as an argument. But it never uses the argument, instead it reassigns the variable with:

```
overallAvg = gradeSum / count;
```

`gradeCalc()` has the same problem. In fact, these functions seem to do all the same calculations.

You're also calling the functions with uninitialized variables.

If `overallAvg` is supposed to be an output argument, you need to make it a reference parameter.

```
void printGrade(int studentID, int count, double midterm, double finalExam, double researchPaper, double groupProject, double participation, double studentAvg, double &overallAvg, double gradeSum)
```

The expression error is due to these lines:

```
                cout << endl
                     << "Total # of Students: " << count;
                << "Overall Class Average: " << overallAvg;
```

The semicolon at the end of the second line is ending the `cout`, so the third line is starting with an invalid operator. Get rid of that semicolon.

```
                cout << endl
                     << "Total # of Students: " << count
                     << "Overall Class Average: " << overallAvg;
```

This might also fix the warning about the unused variable, since you're using the variable in this output statement.

Comment: i changed what you suggested, but now it just crashes.  here is the updated code: https://pastebin.com/60haZ7eV

Comment: Why are you taking all those parameters that you never use? The function reads the values from the file, not from the parameters.

Comment: do i not have to pass the values between the different functions?

Comment: You would if the different functions didn't read them from the file. But both functions get the variables from the file. I think you need to go back and study how function arguments are used.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the compiler. Compile with `-Wno-unused-parameter` flag. It should do the trick.

Comment: Hiding the error rather than fixing it is poor solution.